# Can't Access Angular Variable from Function called by Angular Material Dialog Box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple Angular controller in which:

```html
var vm = this;
var selectedAppId = "";
```

In my web page the latter variable is used like this:

```html
                    <select id="selectapp" ng-model="vm.selectedAppId" ng-change="vm.updateCurrentAppPages()">
                        <option ng-repeat="app in vm.apps" value="{{ app.appId }}">
                            My {{ app.appName }} App
                        </option>
                    </select>
```

During normal page operation the *vm.selectedAppId* variable acts as expected.  But here's the problem:

I have an Angular Material dialog box that allows one to specify a filename.  When "Save" is pressed, I need to access the value of *vm.selectedAppId*.  Unfortunately in this context it is consistently set to an empty string.  I assume this is a scoping issue but I don't know how to solve it.

So here's my question: From the context of the Angular Material dialog box and its helper functions, how do I retrieve the value of a controller level variable?

Robert W.

*UPDATE*
Here is more code:

```html
        vm.addNewPage = function (ev) {
            setIsBusy(true);

            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: editorController,
                template:
                    '<md-dialog aria-label="Get Filename">' +
                    '<md-toolbar>' +
                    '<div class="md-toolbar-tools navbar-default">' +
                    '<md-title>Add New Page - ' + $('select#selectapp option:selected').html() + '</md-title>' +
                    '<span flex></span>' +
                    '<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="cancelDialog()">' +
                    '<md-icon md-svg-src="/images/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>' +
                    '</md-button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</md-toolbar>' +
                    '<md-dialog-content>' +
                    '<md-content>' +
                    '<div class="fileNameIntro">Filename</div>' +
                    '<md-input-container class="inputFilenameContainer">' +
                    '<input id="inputFilename" ng-model="vm.fileName" ng-init="setFocus(\'inputFilename\')" required md-maxlength="100" ng-change="filenameChanged(vm.fileName)" class="inputFilename" aria-label="Filename Input">' +
                    '</md-input-container>' +
                    '</md-content>' +
                    '</md-dialog-content>' +
                    '<md-dialog-actions>' +
                    '    <md-button ng-click="cancelDialog()" class="md-primary">' +
                    '        Cancel' +
                    '    </md-button>' +
                    '    <md-button id="saveFilename" ng-click="saveFilename(vm.fileName, vm.selectedAppId)" class="md-primary" disabled="true">' +
                    '        Save' +
                    '    </md-button>' +
                    '</md-dialog-actions>' +
                    '</md-dialog>',
                parent: angular.element(document.body),
                targetEvent: ev,
                clickOutsideToClose: false
            });

            vm.isDisabled = false;
            setIsBusy(false);
        };
```

```html
        $scope.saveFilename = function (filename, appId) {
            debugger;
            filename = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");
            var currentTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
            debugger
            vm.appPages.push({
                "appId": appId,
                "filename": filename + ".html",
                "content": filename + " Page Sample Content",
                "createDateTimeUtc": currentTime,
                "updateDateTimeUtc": currentTime
            });

            vm.updateCurrentAppPages();

            $mdDialog.hide();
        }
```

*filename* contains a value but *appId* is always a null string.  Why?

Comment: If nobody comes along with a better solution you can always share stuff by declaring a service.

Comment: The promise created by `$mdDialog.show()` can be resolved with `$mdDialog.hide(resolveData)`. Can see how it's done in the demos

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a seperate controller then pass the $scope to that. Otherwise wrap around your code in Material box with $timeout function.

Comment: Everything is in one controller called 'editorController'.  Once again, I must emphasize that vm.selectedAppId (aka this.selectedAppId) works perfectly fine with Angular for all other operations.  It's only when the dialog is launched that problems arise.

I'm going to add all of the code that contains the dialog creation/launch code to help find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be the necessity to add a special value for the scope parameter:

```html
            $mdDialog.show({
                controller: editorController,
                scope: $scope.$new(),
                template: ...
```